# How do I delete Module1 using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to delete Module1 using VBA commands within the VBA editor for Excel.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's complicated.  See this [link](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbe.aspx) to learn more about why.

In short this is what you need to do:

First you need to reference VBIDE

> VBIDE The VBIDE is the object library that defines all the objects and
>   values that make up VBProject and the Visual Basic Editor. You must
>   reference this library to use the VBA Extensibility objects. To add
>   this reference, open the VBA editor, open your VBProject in the
>   editor, and go to the Tools menu. There, choose References . In the
>   References dialog, scroll down to Microsoft Visual Basic for
>   Applications Extensibility 5.3 and check that item in the list. You
>   can add the reference programmatically with code like:

```
ThisWorkbook.VBProject.References.AddFromGuid _
    GUID:="{0002E157-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}", _
    Major:=5, Minor:=3
```

---

Next, you need to grant 'Trust access to the Visual Basic Project'

> Next, you need to enable programmatic access to the VBA Project. In
>   Excel 2003 and earlier, go the Tools menu (in Excel, not in the VBA
>   editor), choose Macros and then the Security item. In that dialog,
>   click on the Trusted Publishers tab and check the Trust access to the
>   Visual Basic Project setting.
>
> In Excel 2007, click the Developer item on the main Ribbon and then
>   click the Macro Security item in the Code panel. In that dialog,
>   choose Macro Settings and check the Trust access to the VBA project
>   object model.

---

Now you can add the code to delete the module:

> Deleting A Module From A Project
>
> This code will delete Module1 from the VBProject. Note that you cannot
>   remove any of the Sheet modules or the ThisWorkbook module. In
>   general, you cannot delete a module whose Type is vbext_ct_Document.

```
Sub DeleteModule()
    Dim VBProj As VBIDE.VBProject
    Dim VBComp As VBIDE.VBComponent

    Set VBProj = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject
    Set VBComp = VBProj.VBComponents("Module1")
    VBProj.VBComponents.Remove VBComp
End Sub
```

Comment: +1, but you should also mention that `Trusting access to the VBA project object model` must also be enabled. I'd definitely discourage against having a project do this unless absolutely necessary.