# save workbook as xls and remove module

Tags: excel, vba

I have a `.xls` workbook with script (module). I try to add few lines at the end of the script, to  save the workbook itself as another `.xls` file while removing all the scripts.

Now I can only save it as `.xlsx` format first, then open that `.xlsx` file and save it as `.xls`.

I google "vba remove module in a workbook" and find [Remove all VBA modules from excel file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18518493/remove-all-vba-modules-from-excel-file) ,[Delete a module using VBA in Microsoft Excel](https://www.exceltip.com/modules-class-modules-in-vba/delete-a-module-using-vba-in-microsoft-excel.html) and [How do I delete Module1 using VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20361241/how-do-i-delete-module1-using-vba/20361456). But none of them works.

Comment: Which version of Excel are you using and what is wrong with the solutions you provided the links for? Do you also have code in the sheet modules and the `ThisWorkbook` module that you need removed?

Comment: For the above codes to work, you need to have [Trust access to the VBA project object model](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSD29G_2.0.0/com.ibm.swg.ba.cognos.ug_cxr.2.0.0.doc/t_ug_cxr_enable_developer_macro_settings.html) enabled....